# Open a file in a runnig eclipse from the command line

Tags: eclipse, macos, command-line

I have two eclipse version installed on my MAC. Both are on the Deck. Both are running. I want to give a command from the terminal like open -a Eclipse  so that one more file opens. But it opens not in the eclipse than I want.

Comment: The Eclipse executable tries to find an already running Eclipse IDE by searching the processes for the name `Eclipse`. In the file `eclipse.ini` of one of the two installations, insert the following two lines at the beginning: `-name` and `Eclipse2`. I don't have a macOS computer to try it out myself, so I'm not sure if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you howlger, this was very helpful. I found the needed information using "ps". In fact it worked a bit different, like: 
open -a [path to needed eclipse ... ... /eclipse] [file name].

I explain why I need it:
I will create two aliases "e1" and "e2". While working in the git command line world I may jump into the Eclipse UI world with one click - e1 [fn] or e2 [fn].

The correct Eclipse popups with the file I am interested in already opened!